# How to open a new view from the collection, on button click

Tags: swift, button, view, popover, collectionview

I have a cell in the collection, this code is written in it marked in orange
This cell is in the "NavigationController" - it's just that I gave such a name
When I click on the button in the collection cell, the `PopOverVC` screen should open, I still do it as popOver
The collection button code lacks present, but it cannot call it because it is a cell in the collection, as I was told, where to add what to open this view

I tried to create a variable, the controller where the collection is located, and so open the view, but I didn’t succeed

```swift
@objc private func setButtonTapped() {
       
    let popOverView = PopOverVC()
    popOverView.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popOverView.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    
    guard let presentanionVC = popOverView.popoverPresentationController else { return }
    presentanionVC.delegate = self
    presentanionVC.sourceView = self.setButton
    presentanionVC.permittedArrowDirections = .right
    presentanionVC.sourceRect = CGRect(x: setButton.bounds.midX, y: setButton.bounds.minY, width: 0, height: 0)
    
    
    let serViewContoller = ServiceViewController()
    serViewContoller.present(popOverView, animated: true)

//    present(popOverView, animated: true)
```

Comment: In your viewController where the collectionView is. You're creating two vc (popOverView and serViewContoller) then asking serViewContoller to present popOverView. This will never work, what view do you want to present?